# How to access enum from a header file in CPP

Tags: c++, oop

Details: C++, gcc compiler.

Say I have a headerfile with some

```
    :
class  myClass {
   public: 
    enum color {red, blue};
    :
```

how do I set the variable color in my source file where i included the file and have declared

```
myClass T;
```

for some reason

I cannot set it as T.color = red;

I get

```
error: cannot refer to type member ‘color’ in
      ‘something::myClass’ with '.'
  T.color = red;
    ^
<path of header file>:77:7: note: 
      member ‘color’ declared here
        enum color {red, blue};
             ^
```

I know I am doing something wrong here.. it will be a lot of help if someone could tell me what.

Answer (score 2):

`enum color {red, blue};` define a type `enum color` but not a field `color`. you need to declare a field either by `enum color field;` or `enum {red, blue} color;`

here is the code works

```
class  myClass {
   public: 
    enum color_t {red, blue};
    enum color_t color;
    // enum {red, blue} color; // or this
};

int main() {
    myClass my;
    my.color = myClass::red;
    my.color = myClass::blue;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: btw the class myClass is in a different header file "myClass.h" which I am importing .. does that make any difference?

Comment: you can't use `myClass` unless you have include header declare it. i.e. `myClass.h`